# Is there a function in Matlab similar to the java function String.split(delimiter)?

Tags: string, matlab

Is there a (default) Matlab function that behaves similar to the java method split(delimiter), where you can tokenize a string based on an arbritary delimiter?

Comment: Worth mentioning that as of Matlab 2013a there is a function called `strsplit` that does it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a built-in function called `textscan` that's capable of this:

```
>> C = textscan('I like stack overflow', '%s', 'delimiter', 'o');    
>> C = C{1}

C = 
    'I like stack '
    'verfl'
    'w'
```

Comment: just saying - `strtok{}` seemed nicer.

Comment: suppose the string `str = 'myfile.txt'` and we want to separate it on the `.` delimiter. So `(str0,str1) = strtok(str,'.')` would split the string on the delimiter specified in the second argument to 'strtok()`. The curly braces in the prev comment were a typo, sorry.

Comment: @AruniRC: true. However, it only splits *once*, e.g., to achieve the split shown in my answer, you'd have to recursively call `strtok`, whereas the `textscan` solution is a oneliner (OK, 2, but oh well :)

Comment: ah. always assumed (wrongly) that `strtok` would work for multiple-delimiters. so then - nice solution? :)

Answer (score 6):

Here are more than one ways to split a string. One as Rody Oldenhuis has just mentioned, and here are some others:

1> Using the function `regexp` :

```
>> str = 'Good good study Day day up';
>> regexp(str,'\s','split')
ans = 
    'Good'    'good'    'study'    'Day'    'day'    'up'
>>
```

2> Using the function `strread`:

```
>> str = 'Section 4, Page 7, Line 26';
>> strread(str, '%s', 'delimiter', ',')
ans = 
    'Section 4'
    'Page 7'
    'Line 26'
>>
```

Comment: @robguinness Works fine in mine. Anyway, the function 'regexp' is better.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function similar to what you mentioned on [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4278) in a package called `xml_toolbox`.

It is called `strsplit`.

> strsplit('I like stack overflow','o')

ans =

> 'I like stack'    'verfl'    'w'